# How to avoid Pycharm inspection error in multiline SQL literals

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently discovered that PyCharm complains about " expected, unexpected end of file" when I write a SQL Query, that spans multiple lines (using parantheses):

[image: screenshot]

It looks like it detects that this is a SQL statement, but only parses the first line.

Any idea how to correctly write this without disabling inspections or writing very long lines ?

Comment: I'd suggest opening a ticket in PyCharm's [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY). The IDE should know that those literals are joined by the compiler and act accordingly.

Comment: Seems to be reported already http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10983

Answer (score 3):

you need a python multi line string

```
string = """select * from table
              where x=1
              limit 10"""
```

if you want to avoid the new lines you can do this:

```
x = "select * from t " \
    "where x = 1 " \
    "limit 1"
```

[doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

[image]

with sql dialect on:

[image]

Comment: The second one would of course be a valid multi-line string if enclosed by parantheses. 
I previously used the first method you mentioned (triple-quotes), but i dislike that this would also include additional newlines and whitespace.

Comment: @powo theres another way that you can avoid new lines, see the updated answer

Comment: if i use the \ one doesn't give me an error. i'm on pycharm 3.0 but i used strings with \ on 2.7 as well and it was fine. what version do you have.

Comment: @powo attached an image it looks ok for me.

Comment: I'm using 3.0 ... in your example the statement in the first line is valid SQL, try for example to put the "where" up to the first line.

Comment: ok i added it and it gave me a warning that i dont have sql dialect, i selected sql dialect and it highlights the where, it gives an error but i dont get the same error as you

Comment: using \ it gives me an error that my sql is wrong when i move the where up, but i dont get `expected, unexpected end of file`

Comment: sorry for bad crop, hover over where says its not expected there, hover over sql says no data source defined. the where becomes red (correctly since its wrong)